# BLE notifications are not working in Android 6.0 Moto G(3rd Gen)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have a BLE device which sends data after enabling characteristic notifications. It is working fine in below Android 6.0 versions. We did required changes to handle run-time permissions and enabling Location service and we are able to scan for our BLE device. But when we're trying BluetoothGatt.discoverServices(), onServicesDiscovered() method is getting invoked and after enabling notifications, onCharacteristicChanged() method is not invoking and after some time it's getting disconnecting.

Any idea what may be going on or a solution to this?

Comment: Care to share your code?